# Do Testofen supplements "increase drive, improve performance, and enhance muscle mass"?

Tags: medications

This is [a paid ad for a testosterone booster](https://www.nugenix.com/report/testosterone_a4d_11212016.php?utm_source=Display&utm_campaign=A4D-ob&utm_content=n-yh-ob&utm_term=n-yh-ob), which seems to be pretty widely displayed

The ad makes the following claim:

> **Studies from India and Queensland, Australia have shown strong and even spectacular results with the key ingredient in Nugenix, Testofen®. Benefits include increased drive, improved performance, and enhanced muscle mass. These benefits primarily come from safely boosting free testosterone levels**.

Is this claim accurate?

I see the following parts to the claim:

- There were studies done on effects of Testofen (Fenugreek plant product)
- Benefits include increased drive, improved performance, and enhanced muscle mass (I'm unclear what "improved performance" means)
- There's a causative effect for the changes from free testosterone boost.
- The boost is safe.

Comment: Seems there's a bunch of lawsuits challenging some of the claims: https://www.naturalproductsinsider.com/blogs/insider-law/2015/01/testofen-testosterone-boosters-lawsuits-piling-up.aspx

Comment: Those are things that testosterone does. If this product is testosterone then we should expect those results.

Comment: Testofen is the product name for a testosterone-like chemical derived from fenugreek. It may or may not behave like bio-identical testosterone.

Comment: It's worth to note that _fenugreek_ is usually used to boost milk supply in women and has a normally estrogenic effect. I'm not sure if one can derive testosterone-compatible substances from it, but I would be skeptical of any male-supplement using fenugreek as a core component.

Comment: @TSar Men and women metabolize hormone like substances differently. Different people may metabolize the same substances differently based on any unique irregularities in their bodies. In other words, testosterone can have an estrogenic effect in certain circumstances.

Comment: @fredsbend Phytoestrogens works only as estrogens, however. Fenugreek is a common additive to hormone replacement therapy to increase breast growth and other female traits on MtF transsexuals.